# Pushing floating elements towards one side of the parent container changes their width

Tags: css

- I want to push my elements towards one side of the parent container, which has a property of `display: flex;`, so that they arent fully visible.
- However, pushing them over resizes the width of my child-elements, once their width exceeds the remaining space. Changing `overflow` to `hidden` didnt solve my issue. What am I doing wrong?

```css
div {
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 20px;
display: flex;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.desired-width {
width: 400px;
}

.hardcoded-width {
width: 490px;
}

span {
white-space: pre;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1 {
background-color: red;
width: 90px;
}

.box2 {
background-color: blue;
width: 50px
}

.box1-shifted {
margin-left: 350px
}

.visible-area {
border: 3px solid black;
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 30px;
align-self: center;
text-align: center;
}

h3 {
margin: auto;
}

h2 {
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Initial State</h2>
<div class="desired-width">
<span class="box1"> </span>
<span class="box2"> </span>
</div>
<h2>What happens </h2>
<div class="desired-width">
<span class="box1 box1-shifted"> </span>
<span class="box2"> </span>
</div>
<h2> What I want </h2>
<div class="hardcoded-width">
<div class="visible-area"><h3>visible area</h3></div>
<span class="box1 box1-shifted"> </span>
<span class="box2"> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go,what i have done in short.**

**1.make a wrapping container that stretches in column direction.**

**2.assign flex grow = 0.5 so 'stay' div and 'pushed' div shares equal height in the wrpaaer.**

**3.in 'stay' div,assign flex-dir=flex-start**

**4.in 'pushed' div, set the width equals to the sum of width of the child items,in this case its (90px + 60px),do not set width = 'auto',because then it will calculate the width itself that is (400 - 350)px or 50px and sqeeze the items.This is the point where everything was going wrong.**

```css
.top-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:lightgreen;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.stay {
  flex: 0.5 1 0;
}

.stay .wrap{
  width : auto;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
}

.stay .wrap .box1{
  width: 90px;
  height:100%;
  background:black;
}

.stay .wrap .box2{
  width: 60px;
  height:100%;
  background: grey;
}

.pushed {
  flex: 0.5 1 0;
}

.pushed .wrap{
  height:100%;
  width: calc(90px + 60px); 
  display:flex;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.pushed .wrap .box1{
  width: 90px;
  height:100%;
  background:black;
}

.pushed .wrap .box2{
  width: 60px;
  height:100%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='top-wrap'>
  <div class='stay'>
    <div class='wrap'>
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pushed">
    <div class='wrap'>
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220276/discussion-between-tawsif-and-tobi).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `justify-content: flex-end;` to **Div** styles. This way you can save on not changing width of the child elements.

So it will look like something

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
}

span {
  white-space: pre;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.pushed-children {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; // This does your job.
}
```

```
<div>
  <span class="box1"> </span>
  <span class="box2"> </span>
</div>
<div class="pushed-children">
  <span class="box1"> </span>
  <span class="box2"> </span>
</div>
```

You can also find some other **Justify** properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)

Comment: I need to keep the .box1-modified { margin-left: 350px }, or at least keep the first element at a fixed first position

Comment: at last I want to float elements to the right of the red box, so that they stay attached to the red element

Comment: But why would you do that....if you have fixed your parent container  at 400px already...how do you expect to have a margin of 350px then have two chilren of 100px each?

Comment: Tell me how exact you want the widths to be distributed.

Comment: the widths of the elements are dynamic. they arent always the same. and showing them only partly is what i want

Comment: maybe changing the widht of the div to auto and wrapping this div in another div with width 400 would work?